# Getting "may not be Null" error when submitting form, even though I am submitting data. DateTime field

Tags: python, django, forms, datetime

Django newbie here.

I've got a form with a DateTimeField that cannot be empty, but am getting an error despite giving a time and date.

Error message:

```
IntegrityError at /app/new_action/
app_action.event_time may not be NULL
```

Sample input:

```
02/08/2014 15:00
```

models.py

```
class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event_time = models.DateTimeField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField('Last Modified')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class ActionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    event_time = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'])
    class Meta:
        model = Action
        fields = ('name','description','location',)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def new_action(request):
context = RequestContext(request)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ActionForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=True)
        #note = form.save(commit=True)
        #note.created_by = profile.id
        #note.save()
        return index(request)
    else:
        print form.errors
else:
    form = ActionForm()
```

Extra note: If possible I would like to keep this input format. For the sake of testing I set the field back to a DateTimeField, but if I can get this fixed I will go back to using [this](http://copiesofcopies.org/webl/2010/04/26/a-better-datetime-widget-for-django/), which produces this input format.

Comment: try adding 'event_time' to the fields list in the Meta class (also, convert it to a list, since you have a tuple)

Comment: That did it. As I mentioned, I'm a Django newb, so what exactly did that change do?

Comment: With Meta.fields you are exposing only the fields in the list. So you know exactly what fields the form is designed to handle. In your case the field `event_time` was missing from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Alvaro, try changing your forms.py to

```
class ActionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    event_time = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'])
    class Meta:
        model = Action
        fields = ['name','description','location', 'event_time']
```